# Starts several tasks at once and then start another task when one completes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a code that runs in a asp.net web api which download image files from another sites.

This is the code that I use to download the images.

```
       foreach (string file in images)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
               await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(file, path + Path.GetFileName(file));                    
            }
        }
```

What I really need to do is start 10 downloads at once. (for example using Task.Run ... or anyother way) and then start the rest one by one when the originally started 10 completes one by one.

For EX.

Start 10 tasks

Wait until one of the 10 tasks complete

When 1 completes, start another task

When another 1 completes, start another task etc...

Until all the images in the list are downloaded.

So I'll have at most 10 concurrent downloads when the code is running (or less than 10 if there are no more images to be downloaded.)

I'm using .net 4.5.2

Can you guys point me in the right direction to achieve this ?

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but have a look at Hangfire http://hangfire.io/ - seems like a perfect fit for your requirement

Comment: You'll probably need to start 10 Tasks, then use `Task.WaitAny(taskList)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SemaphoreSlim` to throttle asynchronous work:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

...

var downloads = images.Select(file => DownloadAsync(file));
await Task.WhenAll(downloads);

...

private async Task DownloadAsync(string file)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
      await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(file, path + Path.GetFileName(file));                    
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    _mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Notes:

- You may want to adjust `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`.
- You should avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. See my [recent MSDN article on `async` ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of thinking out loud here, not sure if this'll work, others will hopefully improve on it:

```
private void startFirst10Tasks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    //tasks.Add first 10 tasks
    taskHandler(tasks);
}

private void taskHandler(List<Task> tasks)
{
     Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks, winner =>
        {
            getNewTasks(tasks.Except(new List<Task>{winner}));
        });
}

private void getNewTasks(List<Task> tasks)
{
    tasks.Add(
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            //Next DownloadFileTask
        })
    );

    taskHandler(tasks);
}
```